# Modal box not pop up

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Modal boxes created with each id. But when click into button not pop Up. No error shown in inspect element.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($listDetails)) {
        $i = $page;
        foreach ($listDetails as $listDet) 
        {
            $i++;
?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td style=""><?php echo $listDet['benefits_title']; ?></td>
                <td style=""><?php echo date('d-m-Y',  strtotime($listDet['benefits_start_date'])); ?></td>
                <td style=""><?php echo date('d-m-Y',  strtotime($listDet['benefits_end_date'])); ?></td>
                <td style="">
                    <?php if($listDet['featured_benefits']==0){?> 
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs">No</span>
                    <?php } else if($listDet['featured_benefits']==1){?>
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs">Yes</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td style="">
                    <?php if($listDet['status']==0){?> 
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs">Expired</span>
                    <?php } else if($listDet['status']==1){?>
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs">Ongoing</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color:#1385e5" data-toggle="modal" title="View" data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $listDet['benefits_id']; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                   <?php if($this->utp==1) {?>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('settings/benefit_schema/'.encData($listDet['benefits_id']))?>" style="color:#060" class="change_stat" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="return del('<?php echo $listDet['benefits_id']; ?>');">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" title="Delete"></i>
                    </a>
                   <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
            <tr><td colspan="7"><div class="ajax_pag" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $links; ?></div></td></tr>
    <?php } else{?>   
        <tr class="">
            <td style="text-align: center; color: red;" class=" no-data" colspan="7" > No data found !</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php
        if (!empty($listDetails)) 
        {
            foreach ($listDetails as $listDet) 
            {
    ?>
                <div class="modal" id="myModal_<?php echo $listDet['benefits_id'] ?>">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Schema Details</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Title</strong></div>
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php echo $listDet['benefits_title']; ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Applicable To</strong></div>
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php if($listDet['applicable_to']==0) echo "Both"; else if($listDet['applicable_to']==1) echo "Private Customer"; elseif($listDet['applicable_to']==2) echo "Corporate Customer";?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Description</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="text-align: justify;"> &nbsp;<?php echo $listDet['benefits_description']; ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Start date</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php echo date('d-m-Y',  strtotime($listDet['benefits_start_date'])); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>End Date</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php echo date('d-m-Y',  strtotime($listDet['benefits_end_date'])); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Featured</strong></div>
                                     <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php if($listDet['featured_benefits']==0) echo "No"; else echo "Yes";?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Image</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/schema/images/'.$listDet['benefits_image']);?>" width="50" height="50"/></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"><strong>Supporting Files</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6"> &nbsp;<?php echo $listDet['benefits_file']; ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top:0px;"></div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div><!-- /.modal -->  
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try removing javascript:void(0) from your link and use #

Comment: still not worling @ Mark

Comment: using template/alternative syntax in php might make it a bit more readable such as this `<?php foreach ($listDetails as $listDet): ?>` html content `<?php endforeach; ?>` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Both IDs, the one in the link and the one in the modal id are rendering the same, right?

Comment: same iDs @Juan Bonnett

Comment: is there a specific reason you have two identical foreach loops? it would be more efficient and easier to keep track of things with only one.  Also I would do `is_array($listDetails))` instead of `empty($listDetails))` an empty array will skip the foreach as there is nothing to loop over,but a non-empty string or number will be a syntax error.

Comment: Ok, perfect, now... Have you tried hardcoding some modal stuff and links to it so we can make sure that the Bootstrap Javascript is loaded properly?

Comment: No simple modal box @Juan Bonnett

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal i think Juan was saying to create a simple hard coded modal to test that the javascript works, which is an good idea.

Comment: not working @Juan Bonnett

Comment: So, now we know the problem is that the javascript is not loading properly. Can you show us the markup for the javascript? Like, if they're declared at the <head> or at the bottom of your page.